# Check login status flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm creating a website with the login system and this is what i'm dealing with:

I have two routes:

The first one is the login page, here is the code:

```
@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login_submit():
    error = None
    if request.form['username'] == 'khoa.programmer' and request.form['password'] == 'HotnCold':
        if request.form['actions'] == 'add-post':
            return redirect('/admin/addpost')
    else:
        error = 'Wrong info'
        return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

and the second one is the addpost route will be redirected after user logged in.

The problem is i don't know how or what to check that user logged in successfully. I want to prevent people just type the url and access the page without permission, simply just show a message to them or redirect them to the login page. Please help!

Sorry about my english!

Comment: You could declare a `class User` that is set to `None` until you login, then to check not logged-in, you can do `if user is None:`

Comment: For example, there is the [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library

Comment: but there is no way to pass the parameter to the redirect function (according to my knowledge) :(

Comment: The Flask-Login library is shared amongst your entire app and sits on top of the existing Flask API, so I don't understand what you are saying

Answer (score 4):

You can use session. This video can also help you as well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WCpNvteLCDI

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, session, flash
from functools import wraps
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'YOUSECRETKEY'
app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(hours=24)

def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'logged_in' in session:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash('You need to login first')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return wrap


@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        if login == password;
            session['logged_in'] = True
            return redirect(url_for('panel'))

        else:
            error = 'Invalid credentials. Try again'
            return render_template('login.html', error=error)

    return render_template('login.html', error=error)


@app.route('/panel/')
@login_required
def panel():
    return render_template('panel.html')


@app.route('/logout/')
@login_required
def logout():
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    return redirect(url_for('login'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host=os.getenv('IP', '0.0.0.0'), port=int(os.getenv('PORT', 5000)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flask-login

```
@site.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if g.user is not None and g.user.is_authenticated:
        flash('Wrong info')
        return redirect(url_for('index.index'))
    if form.validate_on_submit() and request.method == "POST":
        name = form.name.data
        passwd = form.passwd.data
```

or you can use session to check the status of login
when you login in,session['login_in'] = True,and when you logout,session['login_in'] = False

Answer (score 0):

I feel that you are looking to pass your authenticated user between requests, so you can use session

Please read http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.session

```
from flask import session
session['user'] = your_way_of_getting_authenticated_user()
# retrieve your user in another view
user = session['user']
# redirect to login using url_for to the login page if user mismatch or None
```

Please note that you need to set a secret key for your app before using session

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "yoursecret"
```

My way would be to decorate my secret views using @login_required decorator as specified at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/viewdecorators/#login-required-decorator, Here the example is given using `g` object.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Flask-login (but you will need a login_manager too). So [here](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a full documentation.

```
from flask_login import login_required

@app.route('/account')
@login_required
def account():
    return render_template('account.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

create a function that checks for session status.

```
def protectedPage():
if 'userID' not in session:
    return redirect('/log-in', code=302)
if session['userID'] == False:
    return redirect('/log-in', code=302)
```